# Android weight / linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/start_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0000FF" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:background="#00FF00" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff000" >

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

As you see it's weird, I want 10% "borders" at each side!

Comment: post the whole xml, and the result image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout_width is set match parent, in some cases this keeps Android from interpreting the layout_weights correctly. In this case, a vertical layout of view elements (Linear Layout), the solution is setting `layout_width` to 0dp.

Comment: Correct thanks! I knew it was something weird and simple at the same time!